# Ionic: hide backdrop in ion-menu

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework

I have an Ionic app using an ion-menu to open a burger menu. However, I don't want to have the backdrop on the right as shown in this screenshot:

[image]

What I want to have is this (without the backdrop):

[image]

The ion-menu:

```
<ion-menu side="start" type="push" menuId="first" contentId="main" class="burger-menu">...</ion-menu>
```

I've tried about everything in CSS:

```
.burger-menu {
  // Doesn't work
  --backdrop: none !important;
  backdrop-filter: none !important;
}

// Doesn't work
ion-menu#backdrop {
  display: none !important;
}

// Doesn't work
ion-menu > ion-backdrop {
  display: none !important;
}

// Doesn't work
ion-backdrop.menu-backdrop {
  display: none !important;
}

// Doesn't work
:host(.menu-type-push) .show-backdrop {
  display: none !important;
}
```

But none of them seem to work.

EDIT: here's what I'm seeing in the console when I open the menu.
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `backdrop` is inside the shadow tree of the `ion-menu` element, which means CSS will not work.

According to the [documentation](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/menu#css-shadow-parts) about `ion-menu`, the `backdrop` is a CSS Shadow Part being exposed. Therefore, you can use the `::part()` pseudo-element which allows you to select elements inside of a shadow tree in order to style them.

```
ion-menu::part(backdrop) {
    background-color: transparent;
}
```

Learn more about [CSS Shadow Parts](https://ionicframework.com/docs/theming/css-shadow-parts) when styling the Ionic Framework.

### Edit

It looks like the CSS Shadow Parts are not implemented in versions prior to Ionic 5.
You can override the `--ion-backdrop-color` variable instead.

**global.scss**

```
:root {
  ion-menu {
    --ion-backdrop-color: transparent;
  }
}
```

Working fine on Ionic 4.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, I've tried your solution but I'm still getting the backdrop.

Comment: I'm afraid this solution only works for Ionic 5, I can't seem to find anything related to CSS Shadow Parts in the documentation v4. You might have to rely on `::ng-deep` even if it's deprecated.

Comment: My Ionic version is 6.3.0, is there a solution for this version? I tried `ion-menu::ng-deep(backdrop)` but that doesn't seem to work either.

Comment: Is it maybe because I'm also using ion-menu-toggle? I've edited my initial post and added what I'm seeing in the console when I open the menu.

Comment: When I said Ionic 5, I meant the framework version, not the CLI. I have updated my answer accordingly with a new solution, please check it out.